# Was ist der korrekte Plural „Vormunde“ oder „Vormünder“?

Tags: etymology, gender, grammatical-number, technical-terminology

Die gängigen Wörterbücher sind sich einig, dass der Plural von [Vormund](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Vormund) sowohl *Vormunde* als auch *Vormünder* sein kann. Leider steht dort aber nichts darüber, welche Bezeichnung die bevorzugte ist.

Ich habe herausgefunden, dass man die [Etymologie von Vormund](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Vormund) eben nicht auf den Mund (Öffnung zur Nahrungsaufnahme im Gesicht) sondern auf die mittlerweile nicht mehr gebräuchliche Mund, *f.*, (Schutzgewalt über Personen) zurückführt, habe aber nichts darüber finden können, wie der Plural der *Mund* gebildet wurde. Interessant ist auch, dass sich offenbar mit dem Verlust der *Mund* im Deutschen auch ihr Genus geändert hat, also *der Vormund*, *m.*.

Meine Vermutung ist, dass der Plural *die Vormunde* von *der Mund* kommen könnte, also etymologisch korrekter wäre, und der Plural *die Vormünder* fälschlich mit der Genusänderung von *dem Mund*  gebildet wurde.

Weiß man darüber mehr? Welche Variante wäre heute ohne Berücksichtigung der Etymologie die gebräuchlichere? Gibt es womöglich Unterschiede in Deutschland, Österreich oder der Schweiz?

Comment: Ich hätte bei "Mund (f)" und "Vormund" eigentlich eher eine Verbindung zum *Mandat* gesucht, obwohl das eher von der Hand kommt. Bei "mündig" hätte ich geahnt, dass man in einem Alter ist, dass man für sich selbst sprechen kann - Und das würde irgendwie auch auf den *Vormund* passen. Die Verbindung zu *(m) Mund* muss ja nicht bei *(f) Mund* aufhören.

Comment: Und, siehan: *die Mund* und *die Munt* finden sich in genau deiner Bedeutung auch noch im aktuellen Online-Duden und sind dort nicht einmal als archaisch notiert. Genauso wie *die Vormundin*, von der ich auch nicht wusste, dass es sie gibt...

Comment: @tofro Damit hätte ich nicht gerechnet... vielleicht gibt es noch viele Bücher/Artikel über das germanische Recht und man findet dehalb noch eine signifikante Verwendung?

Comment: Und nochmal oha: Hier: https://books.google.de/books?id=IhsVAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA938&lpg=PA938&dq=mund+manus&source=bl&ots=4-5VXn_3Wk&sig=xeRnlTdqUVfmOJXUQbKcEAAcE18&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpwKXN7LTaAhUOKywKHfysDrwQ6AEIQDAI#v=onepage&q=mund manus&f=false wird eine Verwandschaft zu *lat. manus* hergestellt.

Comment: @tofro `manus` wiederum wäre feminin. [Auch Pfeifer](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Mund) sieht eine Verwandschaft zwischen *Mund* und *Manus*, wohl auch, weil die altnordische Bedeutung von *Mund* Hand sein soll. Also doch Mandat! :)

Comment: Zu der "Mund" = Schutzgewalt über anvertraute Personen paßt ja auch die Bezeichnung desjenigen, der einem Vormund anvertraut ist: *Mündel*.

Answer (score 2):

Das [Wörterbuch der Gebrüder Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GV14029#XGV14029) führt unter Punkt 1b) zum Plural dazu aus

> *die korrekte form* vormunde ...

Somit wäre die in der Frage geäußerte Vermutung, dass "Vormunde" der korrekte Plural ist, richtig.

Allerdings wird dort bereits erläutert, dass "Vormunde" zwar die richtige Pluralform sei, diese aber weniger verbreitet ist als die eigentlich falsche "Vormünde". Weiter wird ausgeführt, dass der Umlaut "ü" über die Formen mit dem Suffix "-er" in die anderen Wortformen eingedrungen sei.

Anmerkung: Unabhängig von der Entstehung der Umlautform ist "der Vormund" allerdings immer schon maskulin. Hierzu wird erläutert, dass er eigentlich "Fürmund" heißen müsste, "da ein solcher für die Unmündingen sprechen müsste."

Comment: Aaah - spannend. Dann ist es auch umstritten, ob *die Mund* tatsächlich feminin war. [Adelung schreibt](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=Adelung&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=DV01699#XDV01699), dass es vom Latein stammt: *Mund, im mittlern Lateine Mundius* ... das spricht auch sehr für ein Maskulinum.

Comment: Was zur Zeit der Grimms von diesen als richtig behauptet wurde, selbst wenn es das damals tatsächlich war, muss heute nicht richtig sein.

Comment: Der [Eintrag zu Mund](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GM08114#XGM08114) ist sich sicher, dass in der Bedeutung "Schutz, Schirm, Gewalt" das Wort feminin ist.

Comment: @IQV läßt sich aber nicht weiter darüber aus, von was denn *die Mund* abstammt - Das könnte ohne weiteres und ohne viel Phantasie auch *der Mund* sein.